# How to use a pipe in regex to match the middle of a string?

Tags: regex

I want to be able to match a regex pattern when the middle of a string could change. I am doing this while reading output of a command, so I need to match for other words in the output as well.

As a small example of what I am trying to achieve,

```
str1 = 'This is my SAS test'
str2 = 'This is my SATA test'
```

I want to make a regex pattern that will match both str1 and str2 while keeping the other text in the pattern.

The only way  I see that I can acheive this is by making the regex pattern

```
'This is my SAS test|This is my SATA test'
```

I would really like it if I could make it simple and just have something like this (I know this doesn't work):

```
'This is my SAS|SATA test'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a group. If you don't want to capture it, use a non-capturing group like so:

```
/This is my (?:SAS|SATA) test/
```

This is due to the alternation operator having absolute minimum precedence. By grouping it, it can then process the subexpression properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use a group: `This is my (SAS|SATA) test`.